# JNI FindClass unable to find class from a packaged jar file

Tags: java, c++, class, jar, java-native-interface

I am unable to use JNIs FindClass function to detect a class from a packaged jar file.

If I do not package the jar file (class files not within sub-folders) JNIs FindClass is successful, however I need to detect the class when it is packaged within multiple sub-folders.

For testing I have created a file jvmtest.java:

```
public class jvmtest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Hello from jvmtest main");
  }

  public class innerjvmtest
  {
    public void hello()
    {
      System.out.println("Hello from innerjvmtest");
    }
  }
}
```

Placed it in a folder 'com' and complied it within the folder 'com' via:

```
javac jvmtest.java
```

I then created a packaged jar file jvmtest.jar with one sub-folder 'com' using the command:

```
jar cvf jvmtest.jar com/*.class
```

with its archive shown as:

[image: jvmtest.jar archive]

My Main.cpp file is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
  JavaVM *vm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=jvmtest.jar";
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
  // Construct a VM
  jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
  if (res != JNI_OK)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to load JVM" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "JVM loaded: JNI Version ";
  jint ver = env->GetVersion();
  std::cout << ((ver>>16)&0x0f) << "."<<(ver&0x0f) << std::endl;

  jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/jvmtest");
  if(cls == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "ERROR: outer class not found !" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "SUCCESS: Found the outer class !" << std::endl;
  }
  
  env->ExceptionDescribe();
}
```

The output of the program is:
JVM loaded: JNI Version 9.0                                                                                                                 ERROR: outer class not found !

with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jvmtest (wrong name: com/jvmtest)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:939)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/SecureClassLoader.java:152)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:553)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.access$200(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:88)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$3.run(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:466)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$3.run(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:460)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:459)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:406)
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:364)
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoaders.java:184)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:419)
```

I do not understand why it is prompting that 'com/jvmtest' is the wrong name.

How do I use JNIs FindClass function to detect a class from a packaged jar file?

Comment: It would help if you printed the actual exception rather than your own error message. `env->ExceptionDescribe()`. Also if you showed the declaration of `jvmtest`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the question has been updated as recommended

Comment: "Wrong name" tells all. Your class isn't `com.jvmtest`. It isn't in the `com` package. That's why the unstructured JAR file works. If you put it in the `com` directory in the JAR file it needs to be compiled as `com.jvmtest`, which means it needs `package com;`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding 'package com;' to the first line of jvmtest.java resolved this issue, the packaged class can now be successfully found.